# Combining for-loops and if statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

```
for($whichPages = 0, $whichPages < $arrlength, $whichPages++) {if(($includeHome=='YES') && $today > $alertbegin && $today < $alertend) echo '<div class="msg" style="margin-bottom:25px">'.$alert.'</div>'};
```

Having some syntax issues with the above code. Basically I want to say if in array $whichPages and if other conditions true, then echo html. Not sure how to combine the for loop and the if clause though. Little help. Thanks.

I've got this code that works but am looking to simplify it

```
if(($includeHome=='YES' || $thisPage=='Class' || $thisPage=='Events' || $thisPage=='Gallery') && $today > $alertbegin && $today < $alertend)echo '<div class="msg" style="margin-bottom:25px">'.$alert.'</div>';
```

The $thisPage variables are what I'm putting in my array `$whichPages = array('Class','Events','Gallery')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
$whichPages = ['Class','Events','Gallery'];
if ((in_array($thisPage, $whichPages) || $includeHome == 'YES') 
    && $today > $alertbegin && $today < $alertend) {
    echo '<div class="msg" style="margin-bottom:25px">' . $alert . '</div>';
}
```